# SQL Split Range Down to Individual Line

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

| JOBNO | STARTNO | ENDNO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 5 |
| 456 | 6 | 7 |
| 789 | 8 | 10 |

I need output like this:

| STARTNO | JOBNO |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 4 | 123 |
| 5 | 123 |
| 6 | 456 |
| 7 | 456 |
| 8 | 789 |
| 9 | 789 |
| 10 | 789 |

Comment: Can you show us the query you have written to get the expected output?  What results do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You want recursive `cte` :

```
with cte as (
     select jobno, startno, endno
     from table t
     union all
     select jobno, startno + 1, endno
     from cte c
     where startno < endno
)
select c.startno, c.jobno
from cte c
order by c.jobno, c.startno;
```

This assumes you are running with `SQL Server` if not then syntax may differ.

Use `option (maxrecursion 0)` if the `startno` has more gap.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but for Postgres you can use `generate_series()`:

```
select x.i as startno, j.jobno
from jobs j
  join generate_series(j.startno, j.endno) as x(i) on true;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/RZN4872